# Email is not going from rails app when using siteground mail id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I am using Ruby 2 and Rails 4. I am trying to sending a mail from my application. When I use gmail account it works nicely But when I use Site Ground account it does not work. I have an email account in site ground(http://www.siteground.com/).

I have created a file called email.yml and have written some code like:

email.yml:

```
development:
  :address: smtp.mydomain.com
  :port: 25
  :Domain: mail.mydomain.com
  :authentication: plain
  :user_name: email address of siteground
  :password: password
  :enable_starttls_auto: true

production:
      :address: smtp.mydomain.com
      :port: 25
      :Domain: mail.mydomain.com
      :authentication: plain
      :user_name: email address
      :password: password
      :enable_starttls_auto: true
```

In config/environment/development

I have added

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://localhost:3000/' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Please help me if any one have any idea about this.

Comment: try adding this `config.action_mailer.delivery_error = false` and check for any errors you have

Comment: This gives an error "undefined method `delivery_error`" . "config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false"  is there already.

Comment: make that as true like this: `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`

Comment: Well got this error: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.

Comment: you are saying mydomain.com try add that to this config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.com' } or else add   :address: localhost

Comment: I have written address: localhost.  This error comes  "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)"

Comment: what is domain you are using for the app

Comment: 'development:
  
  :address: localhost
  :port: 25
  :Domain: mail.tritonls.ca
  :authentication: plain
  :user_name: info@tritonls.ca
  :password: ****
  :enable_starttls_auto: true'

Comment: use address same as your domain like address: smtp.tritonls.ca

Comment: geting this error again. "getaddrinfo: No such host is known."

Comment: :address: mail.tritonls.ca  :port: 25 :Domain: tritonls.ca :authentication: plain :user_name: info@tritonls.ca :password: **** :enable_starttls_auto: true'

Comment: Error: "hostname "mail.tritonls.ca" does not match the server certificate"

Comment: :address:smtp.tritonls.ca

Comment: error: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.

Comment: try adding your ip as address and change this also config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://yourip:3000/' }

Comment: Getting same error. getaddrinfo: No such host is known

Comment: Done, i had add :address: mail.tritonls.ca
:openssl_verify_mode: 'none'

Comment: Oh nice finally you get it work

Comment: Thanks for your time anusha. It was good talking to u and you only show me how to see the error when we use mail in rail app.

Comment: Ya finally the problem is solved. Thanks a lot.